# Позиционирование элемента справа HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

[image: описание]

Есть кнопка смены цветовой темы и хотелось бы чтобы она располагалась не в верхнем левом углу, как на картинке, а в правом.

Сама кнопка находится в элементе `top_bar` (пишу на `VueJS`):

```
<div class="collection">
<div v-on:click="toggleDarkMode">
   <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
       <path d="M22 41C32.4934 41 41 32.4934 41 22C41 11.5066 32.4934 3 223C11.5066 3 3 11.5066 3 22C3 32.4934 11.5066 41 22 41ZM7 22C7
                13.7157 13.7157 7 22 7V37C13.7157 37 7 30.2843 7 22Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.collection{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Далее элемент `top_bar` подключается в другой элемент `index`:

```
<template>
    <div class="all">
        <section id="head-section">
        <div v-bind:class="bg"></div>
        <top_bar :toggle-dark-mode="toggleDarkMode" class="top-bar"></top_bar>
        ...
</template>
```

Также хочу чтобы кнопка имела свойство `position: fixed`:

```
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
}
```

При выставлении данного свойства кнопка меняет свой угол расположения с правого на левый.

Помогите понять почему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дефолтное значение абсолютно позиционированных элементов это `top: 0`, `left: 0`.

Когда Вы добавляете свойство `position` отличное от `static` Вам следует указывать месторасположение элемента explicitly, если Вы хотите что бы оно отличалось от значений по умолчанию:

```
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```